# Sunspot Solr Gem & .gitignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, solr, sunspot, gitignore

I am running the sunspot_solr & sunspot_rails gem in development and I get an insane number of changes to index files and data files every time I start and stop the development and/or sunspot server.  It's driving me crazy doing version control.

gem "sunspot_solr", "~> 2.1.0"
gem "sunspot_rails", "~> 2.1.0"

Which of these files/directories can be safely ignored? These are the culprits:

**solr/development/data/index/_dh.fdt**

**solr/pids/development/sunspot-solr-development.pid**

**solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000176**

**solr/development/data/index/write.lock**

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have this in my **.gitignore** and my teammates had no problem after checking it out...

```
solr/data
solr/test
solr/development
solr/default/data
/log/*.log.lck
solr/pids
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be safe to ignore anything in the solr/development/* directory.  Worst case is you find you need something in there to be under version control and you can re-add it.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following (sunspot 2.1.0)

```
solr/test
solr/development
solr/default/data
/log/*.log.lck
```